# Which Saga pattern was implemented in Eventuate Tram Sagas?

Tags: saga

I just spent few days to researching Saga pattern framework. I feel so confused after reading some article from IBM and Baeldung. You may can give a look on them here

- [Saga-pattern-microservices](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/saga-pattern-microservices)
- [Use-saga-to-solve-distributed-transaction-management-problems](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/use-saga-to-solve-distributed-transaction-management-problems-in-a-microservices-architecture/)

In the article, it said we can use Eventuate Tram Saga in [Choreography Pattern](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/use-saga-to-solve-distributed-transaction-management-problems-in-a-microservices-architecture/#:%7E:text=currently%20in%20progress.-,Eventuate%20Tram%20Saga,-is%20a%20Saga).
But The Eventuate Tram said itself Saga orchestration framework. Could any one help me to explain this

Answer (score 1):

Eventuate Tram Sagas implements orchestration saga pattern.
See:

- https://eventuate.io/docs/manual/eventuate-tram/latest/getting-started-eventuate-tram-sagas.html
- https://github.com/eventuate-tram/eventuate-tram-sagas#eventuate-tram-sagas